# Jaxb unmarshall returning null

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm trying to unmarshall a xml file through jaxb.

My xml file is :

```xml
<root id="1">
   <fields>
      <field id="2">
         <values>
            <value><some></value>
         </values>
      </field>
      <field id="3">
         <values>
            <value><xxx></value>
         </values>
      </field>
     <field id="483">
         <values />
      </field>
     </fields>
</root>
```

***Important
The content of the key value can be of any type (string, date, int).

My code to unmarshall the elements:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Fields", propOrder = {
    "cuestionarios"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Fields {
    @XmlElement(name = "fields", required = true)
    protected Field cuestionarios;

    public Field getCuestionarios() {
        return cuestionarios;
    }

    public void setCuestionarios(Field cuestionarios) {
        this.cuestionarios = cuestionarios;
    }
```

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Field", propOrder = {
    "values"
})
public class Field {
    @XmlElement(name = "field", required = true)
    protected List<Value> values;

    public List<Value> getValues() {
        if (values == null) {
        values = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return this.values;
    }
```

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Value", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
public class Value {
    @XmlElement(name = "values", required = true)
    protected List<Object> value;

    public Value(){

    }

    public List<Object> getValue() {
        if (value == null) {
        value = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(List<Object> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
```

I am getting null values in cuestionarios. I'm not sure if it's a bug in the xml this is badly formatted or I have some error in the xml tags. I think the error is in the labels of xml.
The list is filled, but all of its fields are null.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way with the less changes to do what you want (that I can think of) is as below.

Create a class that looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ValueContent {

    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    private String content;
}
```

and adapt your Value class to use it instead of Object, like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Value", propOrder = {
        "value"
})
public class Value {
    @XmlElement(name = "values", required = true)
    protected List<ValueContent> value;

    public Value(){

    }

    public List<ValueContent> getValue() {
        if (value == null) {
            value = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(List<ValueContent> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Edit to reply to comment:

In that case, you could do something like that:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ValueContent {

    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "text", type = String.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "number", type = Integer.class)
    })
    private Object content;
}
```

But then you xml would have to use different label based on type like below:

```
<root id="1">
    <fields>
        <field id="2">
            <values>
                <number>1</number>
            </values>
        </field>
        <field id="3">
            <values>
                <text>value1</text>
            </values>
        </field>
    </fields>
</root>
```

It has to do that because else it wouldnt be possible to know into which class to unmarshall it to.

Another option (half baked thought) would be to use an adapter for that field and try to get the type of the input there and cast it properly.

Edit 2 to show use of adapter:
You could create an adapter as below:

```
public class CastingAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Object> {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Override
    public String marshal(Object arg0) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(String arg0) throws Exception {
        if(StringUtils.isNumeric(arg0)) {
            return Integer.valueOf(arg0);
        }

        if(StringUtils.isAlphanumeric(arg0)) {
            return arg0;
        }

        if(isValidDate(arg0)) {
            return dateFormat.parse(arg0);
        }

        return arg0;
    }

    private boolean isValidDate(String inDate) {

        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        try {
            dateFormat.parse(inDate.trim());
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And use this adapter in ValueContent:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ValueContent {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CastingAdapter.class)
    private Object value;
}
```

For an xml as below:

```
<root id="1">
    <fields>
        <field id="1">
            <values>
                <value>2009-12-31</value>
            </values>
        </field>
        <field id="2">
            <values>
                <value>1</value>
            </values>
        </field>
        <field id="3">
            <values>
                <value>value1</value>
            </values>
        </field>
    </fields>
</root>
```

It would do the work.

Comment: That solution is not valid for me since the values ​​of my xml can be of any type (String, Date, int), hence the Object

Comment: The xml code can not be changed.
Any solution that suits the specifications?

Comment: @Diego there is a solution, I added it in the response. Check if it is to your liking.

Comment: it´s works, but  the jaxb processing is stopped when the following field is found:<field id="483">
         <values />
      </field>
I've tried with required = false, but it keeps stopping.

Comment: @Diego what do you mean with stopped? I tried your example and it works fine

Comment: Added new example,please try it, and you will see that when the value field does not exist, the processing stops

Comment: @Diego I did, it still works. Is there a stacktrace you see?